# Store value of a string obj into array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sorting a array using MVC approach. I am having an array named as "array" in which I have to store some values which will be given at the runtime. In the view I have given a textbox and a button, the user will input some integer values and click the button after each value which will call a JavaScript function and I am storing values inside it and appending it with a comma.

And after that I am calling another function which is sending the data to the controller and storing the value in a object called "str". **Now I want to copy that data of str in my array each number is separated by a comma so I want to store each number individually in each index position and then I will sort it**.

I have created my sorting program in advance and it works correctly and sends back the sorted values to view. How can I store those values of str in my array?

This is my controller

```
   public ActionResult Index( )
        {


            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult sorting (FormCollection formCollection)
        {

            int[] array = new int[5];
            string str = formCollection["value"];

            int temp;
            int numLength = array.Length;
            //sorting an array


            for (int i = 1; i <= numLength - 1; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < numLength - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (array[j + 1] < array[j])
                    {
                        temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        array[j + 1] = temp;

                    }

                }

            }

            foreach (int num in array)
            {
                ViewData["data"] += num.ToString();
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
```

This is my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@{
    var i = ViewData["data"];
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script >
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsfunc = [];
var enteredNumbersWithCommaSeperator = '';
function AppendNumebrWithCommaDelimeter()
{

    enteredNumbersWithCommaSeperator = enteredNumbersWithCommaSeperator + "," + $("#txtInputOfSort").val();
        $("#txtInputOfSort").val("");
}
function formPost()
{

        $.post("/home/sorting", { value: enteredNumbersWithCommaSeperator });
}
</script>
<form action="/" id="some" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txt" id="txtInputOfSort">
    <input name="btn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="AppendNumebrWithCommaDelimeter()" formaction="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><br />


    <input type="button" name="btn" value="sort" onclick="formPost();" />   @* formaction = "@Url.Action("sorting","Home")" >*@
    <br />
    <h2>sorted array : @i</h2>

        </form >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each number is separated with a comma in the `str` variable, you can use `String.Split` method.

```
string str = "1,2,3,4" ; // Hard coded for demo
var strArray = str.Split(',');
```

Now `strArray` will be a `string` array where each item is the string version of your numeric value. Whenever you need to do an arithmetic operation of the value, read the value, cast it to `int`(from string) and use it.

You can use methods like `Convert.ToInt32` and [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)  methods for the conversion

---

Your current UI code is a little confusing to me. You are trying to do an ajax call with the data, returning the result (a view?) which you are not using! If you are using the AJAX approach, you should simply return the sorted array (string version) and update the DOM. **Or** do a normal form submit (for this, you need to set the string version of comma separated values to an input field so that it is available in the httppost action method.)

Here is a simpler version of form submit solution (no ajax)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" id="txtInputOfSort">
    <input type="hidden" name="commaSeperatedNumbers" id="commaSeperatedNumbers">
    <input name="btn" type="button" 
             value="Submit" onclick="AppendNumebrWithCommaDelimeter()"/>

    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="sort"/>
    <br/>
    <h2>sorted array : @i</h2>

}
```

and the JavaScript to create the comma separated string and set to the hidden field.

```
function AppendNumebrWithCommaDelimeter() {

    var r = '';
    var v = $("#commaSeperatedNumbers").val();
    if (v !== "") {
        r = $("#commaSeperatedNumbers").val() + "," + $("#txtInputOfSort").val();
    } else {
        r =  $("#txtInputOfSort").val();
    }

    $("#txtInputOfSort").val("");
    $("#commaSeperatedNumbers").val(r);
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action method,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string commaSeperatedNumbers)
{
    var strArray = commaSeperatedNumbers.Split(',');
    // Do your sorting here and update the commaSeperatedNumbers variable.
    ViewData["data"] = commaSeperatedNumbers;
    return View();
}
```

That is the simple working version of the non-ajax solution. Add the needed null checks etc to improve it.

Comment: thanks for this help but i am still confuse that how to store the splited value can u give the complete demo please

Comment: i am sorry for this trouble but can you write a code example so that i can look into that and follow the same steps in my program because i am getting errors

Comment: ohh i am sorry for that result thing i wasw trying something else please ignore that part and i am returning my view to index so that the data can get to myrequired location where my view is

Comment: please tell me how to get those values by giving a code example and there is one more problem . i used a debug to see the values after spliting them so what happend is in my [0] index i am getting a blank value because when my javascript was called it was storing the values like this(,2,3,4)(these are demo values) the first position is a coma so i think that is the problem how can i resolve that and store it in array???

Comment: See the updated post. That has a working sample. Also remember, no-one will write the full code you want. People are here to help.

Comment: i got your point but i want to know that instead of array now i can directly use strarray here?

Comment: can you please tell me how to convert and store the data of strarray into array please just one line of code help me

Comment: `String.Split` method converts the comma separated string to a string array.

Comment: i am beginner this is not helping me i am sorry but i am still at the same position

Comment: can you tell me the syntax that you mentioned above like array = Int32.Tryparse(strarray); i know this is not the right way but can you give me the right way for it ?

Comment: The answer has a link to the main documentation which has example code.